# ***aborting after fassert() failure MongoDB on Mac

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am new with express, node & mongoDB and am running into issues while trying it install mongo. I am reciving this error when I run this command,

```
mongod --dbpath SM:NodeTestApp101\data


    015-11-08T08:24:01.771-0700 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] Failed to 
    unlink socket file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock errno:13 Permission denied
    2015-11-08T08:24:01.771-0700 I -        [initandlisten] Fatal 
    Assertion 28578
    2015-11-08T08:24:01.771-0700 I -        [initandlisten] 
    ***aborting after fassert() failure
```

Can anyone out there help me solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run this command as the mongodb user

```
sudo -u mongodb mongod --dbpath SM:NodeTestApp101\data
```